# How to recognize vertical text from Image android

Tags: android, ocr, android-studio-3.0, text-recognition

```
I want to implement functionality for text recognition vertical in Android. Please suggest best possible way.

Text of image like this 


A
B
C
D
E

Output like this:
ABCDE
```

Comment: can you show me your work which you can for this functionality ?

Comment: I didn't implement any functionality yet. I am looking for text recognize library which should be open source.

please suggest me best possible way @Niceumang

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firebase for this
follow the given below link, will helpful for you
happy coding

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android/#0

Comment: what're the issues, you have get